# MUI Slider 'onChange' not changing 'value'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, onchange

I am trying to replace a numeric input control with an MUI Slider though whenever the slider is dragged the 'onChange' doesn't seem to want to change anything. It spits out a NAN error in the debug.

"Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string."

I still have the numeric input running along side it. Upon change of the numeric input the slider does react and move on its own accordingly to show current value.

Help is much appreciated!

```
for (let i = 0; i < bones.length; i++) {
        let bone = bones[i].bone;
        
        controls.push(
            <div className="bone-control" key={i}>
                <p>{bones[i].name}</p>
                <div className="flex-container">
                    <div className="control">
                    <Slider
                        size="small"
                        aria-label="Small"
                        className="numeric-input"
                        min={-3.1}
                        max={3.1}
                        step={0.1}
                        value={Number(this.state[bone].x).toFixed(2)}
                        onChange={value => {
                            this.setState({[bone]: {x: value, y: this.state[bone].y, z: this.state[bone].z}});
                            window.changeRotation(bone, value, "x");
                        }}
                    />
                        <NumericInput
                            className="numeric-input"
                            min={-3.1}
                            max={3.1}
                            step={0.1}
                            value={Number(this.state[bone].x).toFixed(2)}
                            onChange={value => {
                                this.setState({[bone]: {x: value, y: this.state[bone].y, z: this.state[bone].z}});
                                window.changeRotation(bone, value, "x");
                            }}/>
                    </div>
```

Comment: According to their [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slider/), the `onChange` handler takes three arguments: `(event: Event, newValue: number | number[], activeThumb: number)`. So the problem is that you're trying to process `Event` as `Number`.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I am totally new to this and am working off a fork here so I'm crawling my way through. Could you show me what it should look like?

Comment: You could try `onChange={(event, value) => { this.setState({[bone]: {x: value, ....`

Answer (score 0):

> You could try onChange={(event, value) => { this.setState({[bone]: {x:
> value, .... –  tromgy Aug 25 at 2:21

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).